# Get a range of lines from a file and replace a line in that range using awk or sed or both

Tags: samba, shell-script, sed, awk, bash-scripting

I would like to replace a line in a section of the smb.conf file using either awk or sed or both if need be. Here's the section in the file...

`[CMI]
    oplocks = no
    wide links = no
    writeable = yes
    delete readonly = yes
    path = /LOCALSITE/CMI
    comment = CMI Data
    write list = @cbishare 
    valid users = @cbishare
    create mode = 775
    directory mode = 775`

I would like to use this code for later reuse with a variable to run on different sections of the smb.conf file. So just finding "write list" in each section will not work.

I am able to parse the file and get the section using this code...

```
awk '/\[\CMI\>\]/,/^$/' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

or with sed...

```
sed -n '/\[\CMI\>\]/,/^$/{p}' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

I now need to replace in the file a specific line in that range like 'write list'. I am a novice with sed or awk and I haven't found any info on how to accomplish the last part.

I thought maybe i could get the NR of the line and then use sed to rewrite it.

Any thoughts on how to do this or links to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With `sed`

To replace the value of "write list" in the CMI section and only the CMI section:

```
sed '/\[\CMI\>\]/,/^$/ s/\s*write list =.*/ write list = New Value/' smb.conf
```

This replaces the old value of `write list` with `New Value`.  It assumes, as was assumed in your code, that the sections in `smb.conf` end with a blank line.

#### With `awk`

Similarly:

```
awk '/\[\CMI\>\]/,/^$/ {if ($1=="write" && $2=="list") {$0=" write list = New Value"}} 1' smb.conf
```

Comment: Thanks John. I choose sed version and it worked after a minor change of removing the first "*" in the search expression before "write".

Comment: Actually I didn't need to remove the first "*". It works either way. I also edited the command for inline editing of the file with the -i flag so i looks like this... 'sed -i '/\[\CMI\>\]/,/^$/ s/\s*write list =.*/ write list = New Value/' smb.conf'

Comment: @MattPedigo Very good.

Comment: Reworked it to this...'sed -i '/[\CMI\>]/,/^$/ s/\s*write list =.*/&,new value/' smb.conf'